# Return type deduction of lambda expressions of if-else statements

Tags: c++, if-statement, lambda, conditional-operator

I'm reading C++ primer 5th edition, chapter 10(lambdas expressions), Here is a program that is intended to replace negative values in a vector by their absolute value.

```
transform(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vi.begin(),
      [](int i) { if (i < 0) return -i; else return i; });
```

The author says that:

> This code won't compile because the lambda infers the return type as `void` but we returned a value and to fix this, we must use a trailing return type.

But when I compile this code with GNU GCC Compiler on Windows, it works well.

The author also says that:

> This version compile because  we need not specify the return type,
>   because that type can be inferred from the type of the conditional
>   operator.

```
transform(vi.begin(), vi.end(), vi.begin(),
          [](int i) { return i < 0 ? -i : i; });
```

So, my questions are:

- Why with the first version, the lambda infers the return type as void and why does GNU GCC compiler accept this.*(I thought that maybe because of optimizations).?
- Why with the second version, the return type can be inferred from the type of the conditional operator?

Comment: The lambda uses the returned expression to deduce the return type, so it can't possibly deduce `void` from `return <something>`... There's an error in this book.

Comment: `[](int i) { if (i < 0) return -i; else return i; }` is perfectly fine as of C++14.

Comment: What is written in the book was true for C++11 but got improved with C++14 to allow multiple `return` statements (as long as the returned type matches).

Comment: This is interesting times for C++. A lot of new functionality has been added and updated in a relatively short period of time, so your reading material has to be up to date or you have to ensure that your compiler is building according to the rules of whatever standard revision the reading material was written to address.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: But the same code works fine on C++11?!!! Does this mean an error in the book?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa The code using two `return` statements should not compile with C++11: with C++11 return type deduction only works when there is one `return` statement.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: But I've run the very code on "wandbox.org" and "ideone.com" and  https://repl.it/languages/cpp11 and works fine! Even the trailing return type is removed still works?!! Does this mean this works because of some compiler-feature only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> ... the return type of the closure's operator() is determined according to
>   the following rules:
>
> - if the body consists of nothing but a single return statement with an
>     expression, the return type is the type of the returned expression
>     (after lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or function-to-pointer
>     implicit conversion); otherwise, the return type is void. *(until
>     C++14)*
> - The return type is deduced from return statements as if for a function
>     whose return type is declared auto. *(since C++14)*

So the author just describes the situation before C++14, since C++14 the code works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using C++14 compiler , thus it's the real reason.

Comment: @StephaneWamba: I am stuck at the same point. But the OP's code works even on C++11. So is the author wrong?

Comment: @ItachiUchiwa Are you compiling with the right flags?